# Android: id list view

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view declared in my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#F7EFE8">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_message"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when I try to declare/use it to java, the id is not found. But when i rename the list view to something else and try to use it i can see it "R.id.*_*" but when R.id.list I can't find it. And If I didn't use the android:list there's an error that there should be a list view whose id is android:list. Any help here?

Comment: is there anything else included in your layout or maybe extra details you haven't mentioned? I tried that snippet you provided in a clean (with the xml header) layout file and it didn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your ListView object id should be specified either as **android:id="@android:id/list"**

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

or it should have some other id like **android:id="@+id/sampleList"**

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sampleList);
```

Check this : [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

and [list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#list)

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 3):

In xml layout use,

```
 <ListView
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 />
```

In Java Code:

```
 ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);// it takes id of listview from xml
```

if you need to use android id for listview then replace your code as

```
<ListView
 android:id="@+android:id/list"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

It may help you..

Comment: wat code u have used?did u use my first part of my answer? please post your error.

Comment: No need to add the `+` infront of the android id for the second part, because this id is already defined. This is probably why it wasn't working for OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this: android:id="@+id/list"
Then clean project and rebuild. 
In java, just call findViewById like this:

```
   ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html