# ListView in xml layout Does not detected by R.id.XXX

Tags: android, xml, findviewbyid

ListView is not detected in Custom.Class when bridging from custom.xml file ..i have done some silly mistake please correct me..

```java
public class Custom extends Activity {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); // list is not detected..showing error
    }
}
```

XML custom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should put layout_height="fill_parent" too, just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

with

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Whenever you want to give `id` to a `View` you have to use `android:id="@+id/your_id`

Answer (score 1):

`android:id="@+id/list"`
use the notation @+ to add new id

Answer (score 0):

Change the following -- `android:id="@+id/list"`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Now following will detect the list-
`ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);`

If you want to refer Android resources , which are already defined in Android system, with @android:id/.. while to access resources that you have defined/created in your project, you use @id/.

Check this SO -- [Difference between "@id/" and "@+id/" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)

So for your case, you can also define list view by `android:id="@android:id/list"`  
Also you can check this so [Android: id list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410099/android-id-list-view)

Answer (score 0):

Using @id/android:list is for referencing the default list in a ListActivity.

You could change your Activity to a ListActivity and reference the ListView in your activity code with the getListView() method. For example:

```
public class Custom extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        ListView lv = getListView();
    }
}
```

Alternatively as others have suggested you could use:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

Instead of:

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```